# PageLoad Wont work properly on jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, android, html, jquery-mobile

I cant get this to work:

```
$('#guiacategs').live('pagecreate', function(event, ui) {
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Carregando Categorias...";
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    if(CategFornsFetched == 0) {
        $.getJSON('http://www.casamentojundiai.com.br/scripts/mobile/getguiacategs.php?callback=?', function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                $("#listaCateg").append('<li><a href="guia.html" onclick="genForns(' + val.id + ');">' + val.descricao + '</a></li>');
            });
            $("#listaCateg").listview('refresh');
        });
        CategFornsFetched = 1;
    }
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

but this works, when i call the stop loading before:

```
$('#guiacategs').live('pagecreate', function(event, ui) {
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Carregando Categorias...";
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

    if(CategFornsFetched == 0) {
        $.getJSON('http://www.casamentojundiai.com.br/scripts/mobile/getguiacategs.php?callback=?', function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                $("#listaCateg").append('<li><a href="guia.html" onclick="genForns(' + val.id + ');">' + val.descricao + '</a></li>');
            });
            $("#listaCateg").listview('refresh');
        });
        CategFornsFetched = 1;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Page Loading Message is to be set in the Mobile Init

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Example:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    //apply overrides here
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Carregando Categorias...";
});
```

Then you should be able to use the methods to show/hide the loading message

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

Example (Not tested):

```
$('#guiacategs').live('pagecreate', function(event, ui) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    if(CategFornsFetched == 0) {
        $.getJSON('http://www.casamentojundiai.com.br/scripts/mobile/getguiacategs.php?callback=?', function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                $("#listaCateg").append('<li><a href="guia.html" onclick="genForns(' + val.id + ');">' + val.descricao + '</a></li>');
            });
            $("#listaCateg").listview('refresh');
        });
        CategFornsFetched = 1;
    }
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```